# Can't read messages with a read session with Mesibo SDK on Android

Tags: android, mesibo

With mesibo on Android, we are trying to read messages that I sent or received from a user.
We initialize a read session like this:

```
Mesibo.addListener(this)
mReadSession = ReadDbSession("test-address", 0, null, this)
mReadSession.start()
```

When we reach the point to start reading messages and we call

```
val readCount = mReadSession.read(30)
```

that function returns `-1` in `readCount` meaning that probably it encountered some errors while doing so.

We tried to use the same code as the sample app and the documentation, but for some reason we can't make it to work.
What can be the causes of a `-1` read count from the read session?

Thanks

Comment: Your code was unlikely to have been compiled. There is no such method as mReadSession.start()

Also, if the `read` is returning -1, your database is not initialized. Refer sample code here. 

https://github.com/mesibo/samples/blob/master/android/kotlin/FirstAppKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/mesibo/firstapp/MainActivity.kt

Comment: @mesibo Something is missing... the read function is available in the SDK. Android Studio autocompletion is suggesting it and also I can see you are using it in some parts of the examples. For example here: https://github.com/mesibo/ui-modules-android/blob/2987faf76ddbf23923e643303387914342c7b381/Messaging/messaging/src/main/java/com/mesibo/messaging/MessagingFragment.java#L726  
I don't think the db is not initialized because I can get the mesibo profiles from there. We can also get and send real time messages (using listeneres) but when we call `read` or `sync`, we have these problems...